# Coordinate mix up

Tags: qgis, google-earth, coordinate-system

I am working on a basic map, pulling coordinates from google earth, converting them to decimal degrees in excel, and then importing them into qgis. I am using qgis 1.8. When converting from degrees, minutes, seconds I get a coordinate in decimal degrees that looks like this (37.01879,-77.15026). This seems to be the correct gps coordinate for this given address. However, I imported my excel file as a delimiyed csv file, and found that none of the coordinates matched up. My project in qgis vis projected in wgs 84. I manually input the location in qgis, and the coordinates that were given back to me were this (11776056.2,3715032.7). I thought this might be because map units were set to meters, wrong projection, etc. But I cannot seem to figure out the issue. I have the same problem any time I try to take coordinates from Google Earth.

Comment: I think your question needs to be expanded: What exactly are you doing? what is the coordinate system in QGIS. WHat happens when you export from Excel to CSV? Do you see the same coordinates in both?

Answer (score 1):

Unless your point is in the Antarctic, I guess you want (-77.15026, 37.01879)

In QGIS, coordinates are always East, North, not vice versa.

If you have coordinates in meters, look at the bottom left which Coordinate System is active.
WGS84 and coordinates in Meters does not make sense. WGS84 (EPSG:4326) is usually in degrees.

You can load a Openstreetmap or Google background with the Openlayers plugin, if your project CRS is EPSG:3857. With the background, you cansee if your point is at the right place.

Comment: Could the coordinate potentially be supposed to read as(37.01879,77.15026)? My whole project is projected in wgs84. I have tried to enter the coordinates as both(37.01879,-77.15026) and(37.01879,77.15026). I am working with a basemap that I got from a city government site. The mouse over coordinates in my qgis program spit out coordinates all similar to(11776056.2,3715032.7).

Comment: 77° North is in the Arctic Sea, 77°South in the Antarctic. So remaining possibilities are China and Virgina. If your basemap has such high coordinates, it is not in WGS84. You have to georeference the map to use it with other data.

Comment: Virginia is what im looking for. The problem is when I import my csv file and set the fields for latitude and longitude, they do not match up with the crs in my project. I am only working with shapefiles which are all projected in wgs84 and my project projection is wgs84. I am confused as to why the coordinates are not the same in qgis, because this seems to be messing with the coordinates that I collected

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, in QGIS it has to be longitude first, West of Greenwich negative (-77), then latitude (37).

Comment: They still dont match up even when I set the x value as longitude and the y value as latitude

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: Bear in mind that you can set Google Earth to show UTM (projected) coordinates if required. These might be easier than lat/lon for you to work with.